# Vi/Vim 8 on debian stretch : filetype "bindzone" not loaded automatically

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

When opening a bind zone file, I have to type by hand `:set ft=bindzone` to get syntax highlighting. It's not set automatically on load.

On another hand others filetypes (such as php, perl or kind) are properly set.

Where I should look first to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the filetype bindzone is supported by default in Vim using the [filetype.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/filetype.vim#L297-L307) in `$VIMRUNTIME` which sets the filetype according to the properties of your file. By default however, Vim only sets the filetype to `bindzone` if the file is called `named.root` and for any file that has the extensions `.db` and the first 4 lines match this regex:

```
'^; <<>> DiG [0-9.]\+ <<>>\|BIND.*named\|$ORIGIN\|$TTL\|IN\s\+SOA'
```

If your files do not match that, consider renaming them (if that is the cause for not detecting it properly), add a modeline as shown by @grodzik or enhance the filetype detection logic (see the [faq question 26.8](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.8)).

Also, in case you suspect a bug in the default filetype.vim file, consider creating a PR at the [vim/vim](https://github.com/vim/vim) repository suggesting a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

`filetype` is set based on the file extension or by `ftdetect` plugins.
For example `PHP` files end with `.php` and Vim loads if it exist a file `php.vim` from directories like `ftplugin`, `syntax` etc (they need to be in Vim's runtime paths). So your files either should have extension `.bindzone` or if they have different extension then you can link in your `$HOME/.vimrc/syntax/<extension>.vim` pointing to where the bindzone syntax file is.

You can also add modeline in those files with `set ft=bindzone`. A modeline is first or last line in a file that is a valid comment for that file type and contains something like this: `vim: set ft=bindzone:` (there can be more settings there). See `:help modeline` for more info.

Another solution would be to add `autocmd` that will set file type for files matching a pattern, for example all files in particular directory:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/bind/zone/files/* set ft=bindzone
```

One more solution is to write a `ftdetect` plugin, but I don't have experience with that. You can checkout files in `ftdetect` directories for more info or the Vim's help.